# Paypal Subscription Payment Method

Tags: javascript, json, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I need help figuring out how to setup a subscription service on paypal using credit/debit card in js.

currently i get approval_pending for paypal payment method but id like to know what needs to be inculded in the json string for the credit/debit card so that i can also add a cancelation button as well.

This is the json string:

```
var data = {
      "plan_id": "P-",
      "start_time": "2023-08-06T00:00:00Z",
      "shipping_amount": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "value": "5.00"
      },
      "subscriber": {
        "name": {
          "given_name": "FooBuyer",
          "surname": "Jones"
        },
        "email_address": "foobuyer@example.com",
        "shipping_address": {
          "name": {
            "full_name": "John Doe"
          },
          "address": {
            "address_line_1": "2211 N First Street",
            "address_line_2": "Building 17",
            "admin_area_2": "San Jose",
            "admin_area_1": "CA",
            "postal_code": "95131",
            "country_code": "US"
          }
        }
      },
      "application_context": {
        "brand_name": "Example Inc",
        "locale": "en-US",
        "shipping_preference": "SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS",
        "user_action": "SUBSCRIBE_NOW",
        "payment_method": {
          "payer_selected": "PAYPAL",
          "payee_preferred": "IMMEDIATE_PAYMENT_REQUIRED"
        },
        "return_url": "https://example.com/return",
        "cancel_url": "https://example.com/cancel"
      }
    };
```

I'd really appreciate it if i could get the json string in js for credit/debit cards for creating a subscription for a user along with any necessary additional information.

Comment: PayPal Subscriptions need to be approved. Create a button for approval by following the information in the guide: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/#link-createpaymentbutton . (If you haven't done that yet, it's far more important than cancelling something that hasn't been approved yet.)

Comment: @PrestonPHX The pending approval isn't my biggest concern being able to to cancel and update card subscriptions is the tricky part. But, thanks

Comment: Your question should start with an approved subscription result then, with details about how it was both created and approved.

Comment: @PrestonPHX The approved subscription result works with a credit/debit card signup. I haven't tested the paypal acc subscription method. Regardless of whether the card is approved or not I'm asking for help getting the json body code so that i can set it up myself. This can also help me test out different apis and methods until landing on the correct pipeline. Hence, I'm not asking for the entire code I just need to be directed (not the  suggested comment that u gave, but still helpful). There's nothing wrong with the way that i asked the question

Comment: @PrestonPHX The code i used was from postman. Wen i find the export I'll share it. Also sharing the code and all can unnecessarily lengthen the question. I'm avoiding such